# cannot load background images when the source URL is provided in stylesheet instead of HTML code, Using django STATIC_URL

Tags: html, css, django, web-development-server

I am unable to load the background image of my webpage when using {static} in my CSS code
It's difficult to explain so I will just paste the screenshots,

Inside settings.py I have configured STATIC items as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') ,]
   
# ]
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

I have used the command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

to collect all the static items inside the assets folder(in the base directory)

images/files, for example "ii.jpg" inside project/static/img whose source provided in the HTML template render fine using this code

```
<div class="imgbox"><img src="{%static 'img/ii.jpg'%}"></div>
```

but then I try to render image using :

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),#05071a) ,url("{%static 'img/ff_1.jpg'%}") no-repeat center center/cover;
```

the browser console gives 404(image not found error) even when the name and extension are correct
see console image

[image]
I will attach the screenshot of the error shown in the browser console.
Now, one more thing, when I hover over the {%static 'image_name'%}, I think it shows me the interpreted path as shown in 2nd screenshot:
vscode interpreted path I guess

[image]

I feel like it's looking for img folder in **project/static/styles/** instead of **project/static/**
if that's the error IDK how to fix this
please refer the 3rd screenshot to see my folder structure(carnival is the app's name,ITAproject is name of the project(inside base-directory),templates(HTML files),static(images,css))
Folder structure

[image]

I have also used the {% load static %} tag in the respected css and html files

Answer (score 1):

Django static doesn't work in css files.
You can use
relative path like this

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),#05071a) ,url("static/img/ff_1.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
```

Or use inline css

```
<div style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),#05071a) ,url({%static 'img/ff_1.jpg'%}) no-repeat center center/cover;" >

</div>
```

Comment: When I use relative path, it looks for the static folder inside the styles folder, means: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/ss%20(1).jpg instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/ss%20(1).jpg , just look at the folder hierarchy , maybe u will get it

Comment: use `../img/ff_1.png`